# Open & save files with specific extension always with encoding OEM 850?

Tags: windows, notepad++, encoding

How can I force Notepad++ to always open and save my *.cmd files with encoding OEM 850?

I'm using a german Windows and I like to use vowels in my batch file explanations.
To see them correctly, I have to change the encoding manually for every *.cmd every time I save them.

How can I change the settings to let Notepad++ know that my *.cmd have to be opened and saved always with OEM 850?

Manual steps: Encoding -> Characters Set -> Western European -> OEM 850